# Opening a local or remote file Widget

Tags: gwt

I was wondering if anyone knew of a widget that I could use to list/open a local/remote file within the GWT.

I thought I could use the FileUpload object but I can't figure out how to tell it where to browse.

Is it possible to tell the FileUpload object to look somewhere other than the local filesystem?

If not is there a simple widget where I can point it to a directory albeit local or remote via RPC?

Thanks,

C

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a GWT issue, it's an issue of what's possible within a web app.  Web apps cannot browse the local hard drive using only JavaScript and HTML, nor can they browse arbitrary remote sites.

You can create a button that when pressed, prompts the user to select a file from their local computer.  Your web app then gets access to the path to that one file - but nothing else.

To actually browse local files within your web app, the only solution is to use Flash or Java.